# LightningChartJs setTickStyle

Tags: javascript, lightningchart

I am using LightningchartJS v2.0.1 and I'm trying to setTickStyle.

I would like to remove all grid lines and set the tick color to 'black'.

Here is what I have tried

```
chart
  .getDefaultAxisX()
  .setTickStrategy(AxisTickStrategies.Numeric,(tickStrategy)=>{
    tickStrategy.setMajorTickStyle(new VisibleTicks( {labelFillStyle: new SolidFill({ color: ColorHEX('#000'), tickLength: 8 })}))
  })
  .setNibStyle(emptyLine)
  .setTitle("RR(n) ms")
  .setTitleFont(MyFontSettings);
```

[image: This is the error I get]

Edit 1:

I also tried :

```
chart
  .getDefaultAxisX()
  .setTickStrategy(AxisTickStrategies.Numeric,(tickStrategy)=>{
    tickStrategy.setMajorTickStyle((tickStyle)=>{
      tickStyle.setLabelFillStyle(new SolidFill({ color: ColorHEX('#000') }))
    })
  })
  .setNibStyle(emptyLine)
  .setTitle("RR(n) ms")
  .setTitleFont(MyFontSettings);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that your code doesn't return anything as the styles.

```js
chart
    .getDefaultAxisX()
    .setTickStrategy(AxisTickStrategies.Numeric, (styler) =>
        styler
            .setMajorTickStyle(new VisibleTicks({
                labelFillStyle: new SolidFill({ color: ColorHEX('#000'), tickLength: 8 }),
                gridStrokeLength: 0
            }))
            .setMinorTickStyle(new VisibleTicks({
                labelFillStyle: new SolidFill({ color: ColorHEX('#000'), tickLength: 8 }),
                gridStrokeLength: 0
            }))
    )
```

The code returns the object created by the methods in the `styler` object.

```js
(tickStrategy)=>{
    tickStrategy....
}
```

That code returns void as the return value.

vs.

```js
(tickStrategy)=>
    tickStrategy....
```

This one returns `tickStrategy`